How does the group act on a lifted curve in a principal $G$-bundle?
Let $(E,\pi,M )$ be a principal $G$-bundle. If $\widetilde{\gamma}$ is a curve on $E$ how is $\widetilde{\gamma}(t)g$ defined?
If $E$ is the trivial bundle then a lift of a curve $\gamma$ in a base manifold might look something like $$\widetilde{\gamma}(t)=(\gamma(t),g_0)\: \: \;(?)$$
so then $\widetilde{\gamma}(t)g=(\gamma(t),g_0g)?$  And for a general bundle we use local trivializations to generalize this ?
I apologize if my thought process seems unclear at the moment. I’m still relatively new to this subject and haven’t been able to find much information about the action. As a result, I’m making  guesses based on my current understanding.

What is the definition of a principal $G$-bundle that you are using? With standard definition the answer to your question is immediate.

@MoisheKohan Basically a differential mapping $\pi:E\to M$ such that 2 conditions are true : 1) the fibers correspond to orbits of the action and 2) there exist a local trivialization to $U\times G$ that commutes with the projection to $U$ and $\pi$, and the local diffeomorphism is equivariant.

Hmm, you forgot the most important thing, a free $G$-action. Can you now answer your own question?

@MoisheKohan This is a part of a remark on my notes.  Been free (according to my notes) simply means $xg=x$, implies $g=1$ for all point in the total space $E$. Can perhaps give me an extra hint, i don't think I see the idea.

"Free" is not important, but an action is: If a group $G$ acts on a space $X$, how do you think it acts on the space of maps $C([0,1],X)$?

@MoisheKohan oh of course you mean I forgot to say what the actions was on the definition. Well $G$ acts on $E\times G$ by $(p,g')g=(p,g'g)$. I mean, that's why I guessed that action on the curve also. Let me think about your question, I think it's helpful.

The group action is not on $E\times G$, it is simply on $E$.

@MoisheKohan I was thinking the trivial case sorry $E$ there was just a mistake I mean $E=M\times G$. In my notes, it doesnt say anything specific for the $G$ action rather that for a local trivialization $G$ acts on $U\times G$ as I wrote before.

Very carefully.

My point is that you do not even need these local trivializations to define an action. Let me repeat: If a group  acts on a space , how do you think it acts on the space of maps ([0,1],)?

@MoisheKohan I haven’t had the chance to fully think about your question yet, as I also work in a restaurant. However, it has helped me better understand the group action. I want to make sure I give a thoughtful response, so I’ll try to get back to you in a few days. Thank you for your time and help.

@MoisheKohan A map $f:I\to X$ for every $t\in [0,1]$ corresponds to a point in $X$ so the group can act naturally $fg$ for all $t$ (since we have an action on $X$,) "treating" it as points in $X$ ? But then I have some questions, Lets say   $g$ acts on a lift $\widetilde{\gamma}$, of some curve $\gamma$, then the new curve $\delta=\widetilde{\gamma}g$ may not necessarily be a lift of the same curve $\gamma$ right ?

@MoisheKohan I still haven't understood if $\delta$ should be  a lift of the same curve $\gamma$. I know that points in the same fiber should be equivariant, but i don't think this can apply here since $\widetilde{\gamma}(tg)$  doesn't makes sense.
